# Remove invalid character in json in R

Tags: r, json

Two problems.

1. I have a large file with sensor data exported in json format in txt files.

When I use jsonlite to parse it:

```
json1 <- fromJSON(txt = "temp.txt")
```

I receive:

```
Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
  lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                   prm,{"event_id":"0d3eefe1-8f7e-
                 (right here) ------^
```

I have tried to run a simple code to clean it:

```
test <- readLines("temp.txt", warn = FALSE)
test <- gsub("prm,", "", test)
```

2. This cleans the gunk out but then when I try to save it back as a text file:

   ```
   write.table(test, "test.txt", sep= ",")
   ```

The file contains this at the beginning:

```
"x"
"1","{\"event_id\":\"0d3eefe1-8 etc
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `writeLines()`.

`write.table()` will convert the character strings to a table. This part: `"1",` is the line number which `R` puts as a new column in the way you save the file. `"x"` is the column name which is created.

What I think you wanted to do is:

```
writeLines(test, "test.txt", useBytes = TRUE)
```

The part `useBytes = TRUE` makes sure the encoding is not changed when you save the file (which Windows annoyingly insists on doing otherwise).